# Mail server Dns zone file configuration

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spf

My server hostname is:

- test02.s80.in

and its IP address is:

- 176.67.172.209

I want to configure a postfix mail server on this server.
Can anyone tell me the correct DNS zone file configuration for this server so that I get a spf="Pass", when I send mail from my mail server to gmail or any other mail server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a TXT record for test02.s80.in that looks like: "v=spf1 a -all".

You can validate the record by using something like: http://www.kitterman.com/getspf2.py

Hey, look, Microsoft has an SPF record generator: http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/

Once you generate your record, you will need to add it to your DNS service.